# Prove that$\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{\left(1-x^{2^{k}}\right)}$= $\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k-1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k}}}$

Tags: partial-fractions

**Question**Prove that$\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{\left(1-x^{2^{k}}\right)}$=
$\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k-1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k}}}$

**My Approach** R.H.S

$\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k-1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k}}}$=$\frac{x^{2^{k-1}\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{\left(1-x^{2^{k}}\right)\left(1-x^{2^{k-1}}\right)}$

i just don't know what else i can do?

Comment: Your step is not quite correct; note that $(x^{2^{k - 1}})^2 = x^{2^k}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x^{2^k}=m$

The equation reduces to 
$$\frac {\sqrt m}{1-m}=\frac {1+\sqrt m -1}{1-m}$$
$$=\frac {1+\sqrt m}{1-m}-\frac {1}{1-m}$$
$$=\frac {1}{1-\sqrt m} - \frac {1}{1-m}$$
Resubstitute value of $m$ to obtain desired proof

Comment: Standard trick, pretty useful !

Comment: Glad you liked it

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k-1}}} - \frac{1}{1-x^{2^k}}
&= \frac{(1-x^{2^k}) - (1-x^{2^{k-1}})}{(1-x^{2^{k-1}})(1-x^{2^k})}\\
&= \frac{x^{2^{k-1}}(1-x^{2^{k-1}})}{(1-x^{2^{k-1}})(1-x^{2^k})}\\
&= \frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{1-x^{2^k}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$x^{2^k}=x^{2\times2^{k-1}}=(x^{2^{k-1}})^2$

⇒$1-x^{2^k}=(1-x^{2^{k-1}})(1+x^{2^{k-1}})$

⇒ $\frac{1}{1-x^{2^{k-1}}}-\frac{1}{1-x^{2^k}}=\frac{1+x^{2^{k-1}}-1}{1-x^{2^k}}=\frac{x^{2^{k-1}}}{1-x^{2^k}}$